# Is it possible to combine web components built with different versions of stencil on the same page?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, native-web-component

Stencil JS generates native web components. I'm wondering if it's possible to combine web components build from different versions of Stencil JS on the same page.

Their FAQ implicitly claims this to be possible:

> **What dependencies does the Stencil runtime have?**
> None. The code generated by Stencil does not rely on Stencil, but rather it generates highly-optimized, framework-free, stand-alone code which runs natively in the browser.

https://stenciljs.com/docs/faq#what-dependencies-does-the-stencil-runtime-have

Can anybody verify this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there should be no reason why not, StencilJS is a compiler so the javascript files generated are pure javascript webcomponents, there is no "stencil" in the bundle, so it would simply be loading vanilla javascript files

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works. The final code is JavaScript which you will be using in the html page. There is nothing related to stencil specific there. StencilJs is not a framework!.